# Can I relate lines of code in VSCode editor?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any way to relate (connect) two lines of code in VSCode?

I mean if I initialize variables at the beginning of the file, on lines 50-100, for example,
and lines, where these variables are used, may be anywhere below (at lines 200, 345, 540, 900, etc.)

So if I could command the VSCode to relate line 50 with line 200, line 56 with line 345, etc it will be great. Right now I just typing in comment "see this", "see there" which is not so conveniently.

Answer (score 0):

You can just old down your [CTRL] key (or maybe it's your [ALT] key) and click on the variable. This should take you to the point of declaration. This also works for functions, classes, interfaces, ...